# Join 2 tables with match of 2 columns from two tables

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have 2 tables :

```
TransferPointType
--------------------------------------------------
[Player(int)] [ID(int)] [Type(tinyint)] [Level(int)] [Before(money)] [Now(money)] [After(money)]
X 
X
X

[Transfer]
--------------------------------------------------
[Player(int)] [ID(int)] [Type(tinyint)] [Amount(money)] [Created(datetime)] [Description(nvarchar256)]
```

The resulting table should look like this

```
        [Player] [ID]                 [Level] [Before] [Now] [After] [Created] [Description]
--[Transfer] = TransferPointType--
```

and conditions

```
match between TransferPointType.player=[Transfer].player, TransferPointType.ID=[Transfer].ID
according to this match add others columns [Type] [Level] [Before] [Now] [After] from TransferPointType
and columns - [Created] [Description] from [Transfer]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
where player=1111 and ID IN (1111,xxxx,xxx,xx,xx,xxx)
```

I think about the left join or union but I am not able to write a reasonable JOIN. If I tried UNION where  i optimalized number of columns, I got to the point where the sql server show an error: Arithmetic overflow error -datetime. So, I tried to convert it with (example)  `select CONVERT(datetime, cast(20140806 as char(8)) )` without success either.

Maybe I'm thinking complicatedly and it could be written by simply select ...

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to ask here. Sample data (preferably as DDL and DML statements), expected results and your attempts will help us help you here. You've also only tagged [tag:ssms] here, which is just an IDE; can we (safely) assume you mean you are actually using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that... below Vlada post the select what was exactly what i try to write..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.type, a.level, a.before, a.now, a.after, b.created, b.description
from TransferPointType a
join Transfer b on a.player = b.player and a.ID = b.ID
where a.player = 1111
and a.ID IN (1111,xxxx,xxx,xx,xx,xxx);
```

If you expect TransferPointType has ID's that are not in Transfer table, then add "left" in front of join statement.